# cant get my angularJS app to work with phantomJS

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs

Using latest phantomJS (1.9.7) on Win8 on my AngularJS (v. 1.2.9) application, I'm not able to interact with my application.
I keep getting the message
`InvalidElementStateError: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"`.

When I call `render()`, I get an empty image;

If I add a timeout to my script before calling `render()`, I get a completely mangled view of my page:
[image]

for comparison, this is what it looks like in any other browser:
[image]

The script i've used to take the screen capture-

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost/app/account#/login', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        page.render('login-phantom.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 1000);
});
```

has anyone else encountered anything like that?
what should I check for?

Answer (score 3):

Timeout won't really help (unless you set it for a super long time) because network response speeds vary from time to time. The best option would be to have a variable that notifies when data loading (on the angular side) has completed e.g. `$scope.dataStatus = 'ready'`. Then you could add a `data-status` attribute to an element on the html and poll it from **phantomjs** side to see if data has loaded. You would do the polling inside `page.evaluate` on **phantomjs**.

Matsko has written a [blog](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html) along those lines and some [sample code](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-SEO-Article/blob/master/.phantomjs-runner.js)

So your **phantomjs** code could look something like:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost/app/account#/login', function (status) {
    var delay, checker = (function() {
        var html = page.evaluate(function () {
            var status = document.getElementById('status');
            if(status.getAttribute('load-status') == 'ready') {
                return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
            }
        });
        if(html) {
            clearTimeout(delay);
            page.render('login-phantom.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }
    });
    delay = setInterval(checker, 100);
});
```

While your html could be:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div id="status" load-status="{{ dataStatus }}"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps